# Android - List app icons in list and run selected

Tags: list, icons, selected

Im developing an Android app in eclipse.

I have a list showing the applications installed, the list is this:

```
            //Listar apps instaladas
        final ListView list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
        ArrayList results = new ArrayList();
        PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
        Intent inte = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        inte.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        List<ResolveInfo> list = pm.queryIntentActivities(inte, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        for (ResolveInfo rInfo : list) {
            results.add(rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString());
        }
          list1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));
```

My questions are:
How I can do that instead of showing the icons name? if I do it

```
results.add(rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString());
```

show me *"android.graphics.drawable @ name of the application"*
And how I can do to run the application by clicking on the list? I tried several attempts, but I make the application error.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

results.add(rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString());
with this line of code I assume you're loading the label of the application, so perhaps you should try loadName or something, check what you can pick there anyway since I haven't done this myself before.

And which error do you get when you click the list? this would be helpful too :)

Comment: Hi! i dont know access to name, whit my method i only get label, icon, desc, logo and meta data...

When I click in the item, the app get "The app has stopped unexpectedly"

Comment: this code:
PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
while(i.hasNext()) {
  ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo info = (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo)(i.next());
  try {
    CharSequence c = pm.getApplicationLabel(pm.getApplicationInfo(info.processName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
    Log.w("LABEL", c.toString());

Will show the active running application names, with a little bit of work I'm sure you'll be able to get all application names on the screen.

About the error, check DDMS and show us please, it's rather helpful for both you and us to provide info =)